# Xcode 7 unit test targeting 7.1 build fail

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode7, xctest

Trying to run my unit tests in Xcode 7,  I get the following errors when trying to run my unit tests:

```
"<FileName>" not found with <angled> include use "quotes" instead:
```

[image: Example]

Of course I can't edit the file since it's Apples (and I shouldn't need to).  How do I get my tests to run?  They ran fine until I updated to Xcode 7.